# Eclipse RCP 4 java web start - Nothing happens after equinox starts up

Tags: eclipse-rcp, rcp

I'm trying to get the Eclipse RCP application I developed to work with java web start. I've followed several guides and came up with a setup that should work (apparently not since I'm making this post).

My web start structure looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKrEW.png (Cant post images because of my reputation)

The plugins directory contains all my jars, and the features directory contains all my jnlp files. APPLICATION.JNLP is the jnlp file I use start everything up.

Content of APPLICATION.JNLP:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="file://localhost/home/imas/Desktop/POWER/" href="APPLICATION.JNLP" >
<information>
    <title>Shipping app - ws</title>
    <vendor>Imas</vendor>
    <offline-allowed/>
</information>

<security>
    <all-permissions/>
</security>

<application-desc main-class="org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.WebStartMain">
<argument>-clearPersistedState</argument>
<argument>-consoleLog</argument>
<argument>-noexit</argument>

</application-desc>

<resources>
    <j2se version="1.7+"/>

<jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar"/>
<extension name="wrapper feature" href="features/com.vangenechten.shipping.wrapperfeature_1.0.0.201603310945.jnlp" />
<!-- OSGI setup -->
<property name="osgi.instance.area" value="@user.home/Desktop/POWER/configuration"/>
<property name="osgi.configuration.area" value="@user.home/Desktop/POWER/configuration"/>
<property name="eclipse.application"/>
<property name="osgi.debug" value="true"/> 
<property name="osgi.clean" value="true"/> 
<property name="eclipse.application" value="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.E4Application"/>
<property name="osgi.bundles.defaultStartLevel" value="4"/>
<property name="eclipse.product" value="com.vangenechten.shipping.product"/>
<property name="osgi.console" value=""/>
<property name="osgi.bundles" value="org.eclipse.core.runtime@2:start,org.eclipse.equinox.event@3:start,org.eclipse.equinox.ds@3:start"/>

</resources>
```

Content of wrapper feature jnlp:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="file://localhost/home/imas/Desktop/POWER/">
<information>
    <title>Wrapperfeature</title>
    <vendor>VANGENECHTEN</vendor>
    <offline-allowed/>
</information>
<security>
    <all-permissions/>
</security>
<component-desc/>
<resources>
    <j2se version="1.7+" />
</resources>
<resources>
    <extension href="features/com.vangenechten.shipping.feature_1.0.0.201603310945.jnlp" />
    <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar"/>
</resources>
```

Content of the feature jnlp:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="file://localhost/home/imas/Desktop/POWER/">
<information>
    <title>Feature</title>
    <vendor>VANGENECHTEN</vendor>
    <offline-allowed/>
</information>
<security>
    <all-permissions/>
</security>
<component-desc/>
<resources>
    <j2se version="1.7+" />
</resources>
<resources>
    <extension href="features/org.eclipse.rcp_4.5.1.v20150904-0015.jnlp" />
    <jar href="plugins/com.vangenechten.shipping_1.0.0.201603291126.jar"/>
</resources>
```

Content of rcp jnlp:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="file://localhost/home/imas/Desktop/POWER/">
<information>
    <title>Eclipse RCP</title>
    <vendor>Eclipse.org</vendor>
    <offline-allowed/>
</information>
<security>
    <all-permissions/>
</security>
<component-desc/>
<resources>
    <j2se version="1.7+" />
</resources>
<resources>
    <extension href="features/org.eclipse.e4.rcp_1.4.0.v20150903-1804.jnlp" />
    <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.help_3.6.0.v20130326-1254.jar"/>
    <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.ui_3.107.0.v20150507-1945.jar"/>
    <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.ui.workbench_3.107.0.v20150825-2206.jar"/>
    <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.update.configurator_3.3.300.v20140518-1928.jar"/>
    <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.rcp_4.5.1.v20150904-0015.jar"/>
</resources>
<resources os="Mac">
    <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.ui.cocoa_1.1.100.v20150315-1253.jar"/>
</resources>
```

Content of rcp 4 jnlp:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="file://localhost/home/imas/Desktop/POWER/">
<information>
    <title>Eclipse e4 Rich Client Platform</title>
    <vendor>Eclipse.org</vendor>
    <offline-allowed/>
</information>
<security>
    <all-permissions/>
</security>
<component-desc/>
<resources>
    <j2se version="1.7+" />
</resources>
<resources>
    <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.e4.core.services_2.0.0.v20150403-1912.jar"/>
    <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt_0.13.0.v20150504-0621.jar"/>
    <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.e4.core.commands_0.11.0.v20150422-0725.jar"/>
    <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings_0.11.0.v20150422-0725.jar"/>
    <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.workbench_1.1.100.v20150407-1430.jar"/>
    <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.e4.ui.services_1.2.0.v20150422-0725.jar"/>
    <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt_0.13.0.v20150901-1347.jar"/>
    <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench_1.3.0.v20150531-1948.jar"/>
    <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core_0.11.0.v20150511-1937.jar"/>
    <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt_0.12.0.v20150511-1003.jar"/>
    <jar href="plugins/org.apache.batik.css_1.7.0.v201011041433.jar"/>
    <jar href="plugins/org.w3c.css.sac_1.3.1.v200903091627.jar"/>
    <jar href="plugins/org.apache.batik.util_1.7.0.v201011041433.jar"/>
    <jar href="plugins/org.w3c.dom.svg_1.1.0.v201011041433.jar"/>
    <jar href="plugins/org.w3c.dom.smil_1.0.1.v200903091627.jar"/>
    <jar href="plugins/org.w3c.dom.events_3.0.0.draft20060413_v201105210656.jar"/>
    <jar href="plugins/javax.inject_1.0.0.v20091030.jar"/>
    <jar href="plugins/javax.annotation_1.2.0.v201401042248.jar"/>
    <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.e4.core.di_1.5.0.v20150421-2214.jar"/>
    <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts_1.4.0.v20150828-0818.jar"/>
    <jar href="plugins/org.apache.batik.util.gui_1.7.0.v200903091627.jar"/>
    <jar href="plugins/javax.xml_1.3.4.v201005080400.jar"/>
    <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.e4.core.di.extensions_0.13.0.v20150421-2214.jar"/>
    <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme_0.10.0.v20150422-0725.jar"/>
    <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.e4.ui.di_1.1.0.v20150422-0725.jar"/>
    <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.e4.ui.widgets_1.1.0.v20150427-1751.jar"/>
</resources>
<resources os="Mac">
    <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.cocoa_0.11.300.v20150507-1945.jar"/>
</resources>
<resources>
    <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.common_3.7.0.v20150402-1709.jar"/>
    <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.300.v20150423-1356.jar"/>
    <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.event_1.3.100.v20140115-1647.jar"/>
    <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.core.commands_3.7.0.v20150422-0725.jar"/>
    <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.core.contenttype_3.5.0.v20150421-2214.jar"/>
    <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.core.databinding_1.5.0.v20150422-0725.jar"/>
    <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.core.databinding.beans_1.3.0.v20150422-0725.jar"/>
    <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable_1.5.0.v20150422-0725.jar"/>
    <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.core.databinding.property_1.5.0.v20150422-0725.jar"/>
    <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.core.expressions_3.5.0.v20150421-2214.jar"/>
    <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.core.jobs_3.7.0.v20150330-2103.jar"/>
    <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime_3.11.1.v20150903-1804.jar"/>
    <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.app_1.3.300.v20150423-1356.jar"/>
    <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar"/>
    <jar href="plugins/com.ibm.icu_54.1.1.v201501272100.jar"/>
    <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.preferences_3.5.300.v20150408-1437.jar"/>
    <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.registry_3.6.0.v20150318-1503.jar"/>
    <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator_1.1.100.v20150423-1455.jar"/>
    <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.10.101.v20150820-1432.jar"/>
    <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.osgi.compatibility.state_1.0.100.v20150402-1551.jar"/>
    <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.osgi.services_3.5.0.v20150519-2006.jar"/>
</resources>
<resources os="Solaris" arch="sparc">
    <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.solaris.sparc_1.1.300.v20150602-1417.jar"/>
</resources>
<resources os="Solaris" arch="x86">
    <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.solaris.x86_1.1.300.v20150602-1417.jar"/>
</resources>
<resources os="Mac" arch="x86_64">
    <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.cocoa.macosx.x86_64_1.1.300.v20150602-1417.jar"/>
</resources>
<resources os="Linux" arch="ppc">
    <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.ppc_1.1.300.v20150602-1417.jar"/>
</resources>
<resources os="Linux" arch="ppc64">
    <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.ppc64_1.0.300.v20150602-1417.jar"/>
</resources>
<resources os="Linux" arch="ppc64le">
    <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.ppc64le_1.0.300.v20150602-1417.jar"/>
</resources>
<resources os="Linux" arch="x86">
    <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_1.1.300.v20150602-1417.jar"/>
</resources>
<resources os="Linux" arch="s390x">
    <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.s390x_1.1.300.v20150602-1417.jar"/>
</resources>
<resources os="Linux" arch="s390">
    <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.s390_1.1.300.v20150602-1417.jar"/>
</resources>
<resources os="Linux" arch="x86_64">
    <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.300.v20150602-1417.jar"/>
</resources>
<resources os="AIX" arch="ppc">
    <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.aix.ppc_1.1.200.v20150602-1417.jar"/>
</resources>
<resources os="AIX" arch="ppc64">
    <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.aix.ppc64_1.1.200.v20150602-1417.jar"/>
</resources>
<resources os="HP-UX" arch="ia64">
    <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.hpux.ia64_1.0.200.v20150602-1417.jar"/>
</resources>
<resources os="Windows" arch="x86">
    <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.300.v20150602-1417.jar"/>
</resources>
<resources os="Windows" arch="x86_64">
    <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.300.v20150602-1417.jar"/>
</resources>
<resources>
    <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.swt_3.104.1.v20150825-0743.jar"/>
    <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86_3.104.1.v20150825-0743.jar"/>
</resources>
<resources os="Windows" arch="x86">
    <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_3.104.1.v20150825-0743.jar"/>
</resources>
<resources os="Windows" arch="x86_64">
    <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64_3.104.1.v20150825-0743.jar"/>
</resources>
<resources os="Linux" arch="x86">
    <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86_3.104.1.v20150825-0743.jar"/>
</resources>
<resources os="Linux" arch="s390x">
    <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.s390x_3.104.1.v20150825-0743.jar"/>
</resources>
<resources os="Linux" arch="s390">
    <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.s390_3.104.1.v20150825-0743.jar"/>
</resources>
<resources os="Solaris" arch="sparc">
    <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.swt.gtk.solaris.sparc_3.104.1.v20150825-0743.jar"/>
</resources>
<resources os="Solaris" arch="x86">
    <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.swt.gtk.solaris.x86_3.104.1.v20150825-0743.jar"/>
</resources>
<resources os="Linux" arch="ppc">
    <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.ppc_3.104.1.v20150825-0743.jar"/>
</resources>
<resources os="Linux" arch="ppc64">
    <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.ppc64_3.104.1.v20150825-0743.jar"/>
</resources>
<resources os="Linux" arch="ppc64le">
    <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.ppc64le_3.104.1.v20150825-0743.jar"/>
</resources>
<resources os="Linux" arch="x86_64">
    <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86_64_3.104.1.v20150825-0743.jar"/>
</resources>
<resources os="Mac" arch="x86_64">
    <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.swt.cocoa.macosx.x86_64_3.104.1.v20150825-0743.jar"/>
</resources>
<resources os="AIX" arch="ppc">
    <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.swt.gtk.aix.ppc_3.104.1.v20150825-0743.jar"/>
</resources>
<resources os="AIX" arch="ppc64">
    <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.swt.gtk.aix.ppc64_3.104.1.v20150825-0743.jar"/>
</resources>
<resources os="HP-UX" arch="ia64">
    <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.swt.gtk.hpux.ia64_3.104.1.v20150825-0743.jar"/>
</resources>
<resources>
    <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.util_1.0.500.v20130404-1337.jar"/>
    <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.jface_3.11.0.v20150602-1400.jar"/>
    <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.jface.databinding_1.7.0.v20150406-2148.jar"/>
    <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench3_0.13.0.v20150422-0725.jar"/>
    <jar href="plugins/org.apache.felix.gogo.command_0.10.0.v201209301215.jar"/>
    <jar href="plugins/org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime_0.10.0.v201209301036.jar"/>
    <jar href="plugins/org.apache.felix.gogo.shell_0.10.0.v201212101605.jar"/>
    <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.console_1.1.100.v20141023-1406.jar"/>
    <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.swt_1.2.0.v20150512-1414.jar"/>
    <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.bidi_0.10.0.v20130327-1442.jar"/>
    <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.e4.ui.dialogs_1.0.0.v20150513-0856.jar"/>
    <jar href="plugins/org.apache.commons.jxpath_1.3.0.v200911051830.jar"/>
    <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.e4.emf.xpath_0.1.100.v20150513-0856.jar"/>
    <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.e4.core.di.annotations_1.4.0.v20150528-1451.jar"/>
    <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.emf.ecore_2.11.1.v20150805-0538.jar"/>
    <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.emf.common_2.11.0.v20150805-0538.jar"/>
    <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.emf.ecore.change_2.11.0.v20150805-0538.jar"/>
    <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi_2.11.1.v20150805-0538.jar"/>

</resources>
<resources os="gtk">
    <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.e4.ui.swt.gtk_1.0.1.v20150708-1529.jar"/>
</resources>
```

**NOTE:** I put the gtk linux x 86 version of org.eclipse.swt directly as a resource (without os="Linux" arch="x86") because I would receive no class def found errors. For some reason web start wouldn't load the jar, so I added it directly (Shouldn't be an issue in production, since the application will run on raspberry pi's).

Now when I start javaws with APPLICATION.JNLP I get no error, but the application doesn't start. Below a screenshot of the javaws console

Screenshot of console -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/oN7gt.png

**NOTE** Console doesn't say anything about an error. Normally when there is an error it is showed in the console and written to a log file.

After running the jnlp file, the following folders are added to the configuration folder -> org.eclipse.runtime, org.eclipse.equinox.rcp, org.eclipse.osgi and org.eclipse.update

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: UPDATE: for some reason equinox doesn't activate my bundle. By adding *com.vangenechten.shipping@4:start* in the osgi.bundles I was able to activate my bundle. I didn't have to do this when running it in eclipse.

Comment: Can you please share the several guides that you used... I am struggling with creation of BIRT as JNLP.